# pandas execute operations on conditions - different ways and best practice?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to run multiple different operations on a Dataframe, based on conditions of a value.
I have some working solutions, but they seem like a weird way to use pandas, or are running somewhat slow.
I believe this has to be a common task, so i hope there might be a "propper" way to solve it.
Since i will have to do things like this a lot, i would like to learn it

example df:

```
names = ['john doe', 'jane doe', 'jimmy - tables', 'bobby / tables']
condition_str = ['condition 1', 'condition 1', 'condition 2', 'condition 3']
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]
df_example = pd.DataFrame({'Name': names, 'Condition': condition_str, 'Numbers': nums})
```

I want to run multiple operations on different columns based on one or more conditions and return it to different columns.
In this example split the Name by a different substring (' ', ' - ') and multiply Numbers by different values.

this is a function that gives the correct output:

```
def split_name_condition(row):
    if row['Condition'] == 'condition 1':
        first_name, last_name = row['Name'].split(' ')
        nums2 = row['Numbers'] * 2
        return [first_name, last_name, nums2]
    elif row['Condition'] == 'condition 2':
        nums2 = row['Numbers'] * 10
        first_name, last_name = row['Name'].split(' - ')
        return [first_name, last_name, nums2]
    else:  # needs explicit two return values for the append in iter_lists()
        return None, None, None
```

i can run it with apply:

```
def run_apply(df):
    df[['first_name', 'last_name', 'Number2']] = df.apply(split_name_condition, axis=1, result_type='expand')
    return df
```

or with iterrows:

```
def run_iter_lists(df):
    first_name, last_name, numbers2 = [], [], []
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        f_name, l_name, nums2 = split_name_condition(row)
        first_name.append(f_name)
        last_name.append(l_name)
        numbers2.append(nums2)

    df_result = pd.DataFrame({'first_name': first_name,
                              'last_name': last_name,
                              'Numbers2': numbers2})
    return pd.concat([df, df_result], axis=1, sort=False)
```

Iterating over a DF somehow seems weird to me.

Using a bool index:

```
def run_bool_index(df):
    df.loc[df['Condition'] == 'condition 1', 'list_name'] = df['Name'].str.split(' ')
    df.loc[df['Condition'] == 'condition 2', 'list_name'] = df['Name'].str.split(' - ')
    df.loc[df['Condition'] == 'condition 3', 'list_name'] = df['Name'].str.split(' / ')

    df.loc[df['Condition'] == 'condition 1', 'Numbers2'] = df['Numbers']*2
    df.loc[df['Condition'] == 'condition 2', 'Numbers2'] = df['Numbers']*10

    df[['first_name', 'last_name']] = pd.DataFrame(df['list_name'].values.tolist())
    return df
```

the bool index seems to me more like intended use of pandas, but is very slow compared to apply and iterrows.

timeit results on 100 executions:

```
apply:
0.20913150000000025
iter_lists:
0.16314859999999998
bool_index:
0.7845151000000001
```

Is there any common solution or best practice for this kind of task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with:

```
def myfunc(df):
    df['list_name']=df['Name'].str.findall('\w+')
    df['Numbers2']=(np.select([df['Condition'].eq('condition 1'),df['Condition']
                          .eq('condition 2')],[df['Numbers']*2,df['Numbers']*10]))
    df[['first_name', 'last_name']]=df['Name'].str.extract('(\w+)\W+(\w+)')
    return df
```

Comment: The edit produces a keyerror for me:
```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['first_name', 'last_name'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```
the part before the edit ran fine.

the np.select does help me.
the regex search is smart for my example, but i might have chosen a poor one.

i have to use a couple different functions and operations on different columns and return multiple coumns, based on one columns value as condition.

so the split was just an example for a functions function call i could think of.